# How to make ckeditor as pop up menu

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i also have som problem with ckeditor. How can i call ckeditor as a pop up menu. I want to retrieve a file on the ckeditor. For example .txt file. How can i do to call the .txt file. I implement it on vb.net. I hope somebody will give me guide. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its very simple .

```
If you are using AJAX Control Toolkit then use  modul popup
```

and inside the modal popup panel copy/paste the content of  ur ckEditor.

If you are not using AJAX control toolkit , then also u can use any popular jQuery modal popup like lightbox and then copy /paste ur ckEditor markup inside the div of that lightbox modal popup.

This will solve ur problem.

Thanks and mark it answered if u found it correct.

Comment: Thanks Adam. I already solve it.. but do you know how to save the content without HTML tag..for example <p>, <tr>....